# Git push commit on different branch

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-branch, git-commit

I have a git repository with two branches: `master` and `new_feature`. The `new_feature` branch is created based on `master` to implement a new feature, so before implementing this new feature they are the same.

Now I implemented this new feature and accidentally committed these changes in the `master` branch, because this branch was still checked out locally. Before pushing to the remote, I realized I committed the changes on the wrong branch. If I now checkout `new_feature`, the changes do not come along.

How do I undo this commit to `master` and redo the same commit to `new_feature`?

Comment: cherry-pick the commit from `new_feature` then reset `master` to the previous commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the branch where you have accidentally committed your code

```
git checkout master
```

then reset to latest-head

```
git reset HEAD-1
```

And you will get your changes unstaged in `master` branch, then checkout to `new_feature` branch and commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

**The first way, you merge master branch into feature branch to update the latest code, and then on master branch you need reset code on previous commit
on feature branch**

```
git merge master
```

**on master branch**

```
git reset --hard HEAD^1
```

**The second way: using git cherry-pick**

find newest commithashid on master branch

```
git reflog
```

check out to feature branch to pick commit above

```
git cherry-pick commithasid
```

checkout to master branch and delete wrong commit

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

**The thrid way: using git stash**

uncommit + save changes in working tree on master branch

```
git reset --mixed HEAD^`
```

stash these to clean working tree (master branch)

```
git stash
```

push changes into feature branch

```
git checkout feature-branch
git stash pop
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```